# How to get push message events like click,close,show with firebase cloud messaging

Tags: javascript, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

Trying to implement web push notifications using FCM.

I am able to receive push message with payload on browser using firebase cloud messaging library.

Below is a javascript code snippet.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.1/firebase.js">  </script>
firebase.initializeApp(config);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
    console.log('onMessage',payload);
});
```

How to capture events like click,close,show,etc ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Notification Open

You can listen for notification clicks for Data payloads by adding the following to your firebase-messaging-sw.js file:

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();

  // Do something as the result of the notification click
});
```

## Notification Close

You can listen for notification close events with:

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclose', function(event) {
  // Do something as the result of the notification close
});
```

### Note: event.waitUntil()

You should be aware that to ensure you code has time to complete running, you need to pass a promise into `event.waitUntil()` that resolves when your code is finished, for example:

```js
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
  event.notification.close();

  const myPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do you work here

    // Once finished, call resolve() or  reject().
    resolve();
  });

  event.waitUntil(myPromise);
});
```

You'll know when the notification is shown if it's a data payload because you need to call `self.registration.showNotification()` in your own code, like so:

```js
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
  // Customize notification here
  const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
  const notificationOptions = {
    body: 'Background Message body.',
    icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
  };

  return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
      notificationOptions);
});
```

You can't detect when a notification is displayed for a "notification" payload as the SDK handles both displaying the notification and behavior when it's clicked.

Code snippets from:

- [firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive)
- [web-push-book.gauntface.com](https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-05/03-notification-behaviour/)

Comment: How to close a notification after 2seconds when i am using firebase?

Comment: You can't do that with the web platform.

Comment: self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {}); is not called when i click on notification.